# Last function execute after loged in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, components

i have a problem with logout function. After i loged out and cleared all the cache. I loged in again. And my last function executes again sends post-get-put request.

For example, i have a update profile photo function. I updated on user 1 succesfully. Then i exit from this user and loged in with user 2. At this point another same request sending eventhouth i am not on the profil update page. And the user 2 profile photo updating as weel with same photo on user 1.

I couldn't solve why is hapenning. If you had that problem before i am waiting your answer.

Last component function that i used is execute again after i loged in from other account.

Comment: We need some code in order to help..

Comment: [How to create a minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)